# Pure Dart DOM possibility?

Tags: dart, single-page-application, dart-html

I am learning Dart and suddenly had an epiphany (or *possibly*, an epiphany):

> Can I write a Dart web app where the "view" is done 100% in Dart?

I'm talking: absolutely no (none/zero/nadda) HTML files (.html). 100% Dart code. Something like:

```dart
class SigninView {
    LabelElement signinLabel;
    InputElement emailTextField;
    InputElement passwordTextField;
    ButtonElement signinButton;

    // constructors, getters, setters, etc.

    // Perhaps called from inside constructor...
    void initUI() {
        signinLabel = new LabelElement();
        signinLabel.innerHTML = "<span class=\"blah\">Please sign in</span>";

        emailTextField = new InputElement();
        emailTextField.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"fizz\" placeholder=\"Email\"/>";

        // ...etc.

        // htmlFactory would be something I'd need to write myself (?)
        String html = htmlFactory.newHTML(signinLabel, emailTextField, ...);

        querySelector("#someDivTag").innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```

In theory (that is, my intentions with the above code), as soon as the `SigninView` is created, it initializes a bunch of DOM elements and populates `someDivTag` with them.

1. Is this possible? If so am I "doing it right", or is there a different/preferred/standardized approach to this?
2. Does this introduce any additional/potential caveats (memory leaks), performance or security issues that I should be aware of?
3. If I were to adopt this strategy throughout my whole app, can I assume the app would be quicker to download (less HTML text), but slower to execute (dynamic DOM element creation)? If so, is there a way to somehow instantiate all the DOM elements my app will need up front (slowing down initial download time), and then only make certain elements visible as I wish to render different views/screens (thus speeding up execution time)?

Comment: How will your download size be smaller? In your example you have the HTML you would have anyway, in addition to the extra Dart code needed to create the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an HTML file with the script tags for the Dart startup.
Anything else can be done in Dart.

Comment: That's pretty cool - thanks @Gunter Zochbauer (+1) - what about performance/security issues (meaning, does implementing the UI this way - programmatically via Dart - introduce any other caveats)?

Comment: I don't think there's much difference in security. I would expect performance to be worse because you had to to some things in Dart which otherwise the native highliy optimized Browser implementation would do (like loading and parsing HTML). I would expect the code to become harder to read/maintain. Markup usually just does a better job in defining  UI layout in a human readable way.

Comment: Thanks again @Gunter Zochbauer (+1) - so I guess I have one final followup question: Does this mean that I would be better off  - in terms of performance - downloading all my HTML snippets when my app starts up, and then "binding" them to Dart DOM instances like `querySelector("#someButton") as ButtonElement`? **If not, why? If so, how is this different - again, in terms of performance - than what I'm suggesting up above in my question?** Thanks again!

Comment: IMHO your questions are much to generic to allow a more specific answer. It just depends...